# Particular solution to a difference equation

Tags: self-learning

I'm working through some excercises from Applied Econometric Time Series by Walter Enders.

In the book it is asserted that a particular solution to a difference equation $y_t=a_0 + a_1y_{t-1} + bt^d$ has the form $y_t = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2 + ... + c_dt^d$

How does one come to such conclusion?